Next.js Api is giving a error of `without an `onChange` handler`
Api for nextjs is giving me a without an `onChange` handler for what reason, I don't know.
Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
    at input
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div

Above is the error I am getting, I have tried to fix my handler by looking in to the documentation, I have yet found any solution.
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/dbConnect";
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";

import { getGeneralStats } from "@utils/general";

import Users from '@schemas/users';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    try {
        await connectToDB();

        const { user } = req?.cookies;
        const verifiedCookie = verify(user, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

        const general = getGeneralStats();
        
        const userInfo = await Users.findOne({userId: verifiedCookie.userId})
        if(!userInfo)return res.status(400).json({success: false, user: {}, ann: general.ann})


        const returnedUser = {
            username: userInfo.username,
            balance: userInfo.balance,
            earned: userInfo.earned,
            offers: userInfo.offers,
            avatar: userInfo.avatar,
            referred: userInfo.invited,
        }

        return res.json({success: true, user: returnedUser, ann: general.ann})
    }catch(e){
        return res.status(400).json({success: false , user: {}, ann: ""});
    }
}

Seeking assistance to resolve an ongoing situation, your input is appreciated.
I am expecting to fix this situation.

Does this answer your question? Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler

See controlled vs uncontrolled, and Controlling an input with a state variable
